# How to connect Stripe Connect and Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

Are there any maintained packages out there that allow one to connect Stripe Connect and Meteor.js? I understand this connection is possible but I'm looking for a way to develop this without spending multiple years becoming an expert in Node.Js and Stripe. I am already able to build simple e-commerce apps with Meteor and expect to be able to build out an account / e-commerce / inventory system to support the marketplace payment functionality within a year.

"I previously asked "is it possible to connect them", now I am asking "how to connect them" theres a difference and this is not a duplicate question. people yesterday simply responded " yes its possible", thats not helpful and does not answer my question.

Comment: You already asked that exact question yesterday. I would highly recommend contacting Stripe's support team for help at this point instead: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: no theres actually a huge difference. I asked is it possible to connect them yesterday, but today i asked how do you connect them. theres a glaring difference, but instead you flag my question?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct tutorial at your convenience, you would need to walk down the path mentioned in another answer, that is following Stripe Connect quickstart at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide then adapt with Meteor.js.

Comment: @orakaro how many months / years do you think it would take someone with a rudimentary understanding of javascript & meteor to complete the aforementioned task?

Comment: We can't tell you this. I don't think StackOverflow is the right place to ask those questions unfortunately. I'd recommend hiring a freelancer to help you build this while teaching you.